# How to get Custom Field Values on a Work Item from Devops API

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to get the values from custom fields that are on a Work Item in devops via the API?

I've tried both the $expand=all and fields options from the [Get Work Items API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and couldn't get the data I was looking for.  When trying with the fields option, I tried with both name and referencename values from the [Fields API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/fields/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) without success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use simple "GET WORK ITEM" API:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=6.0
```

Note, you will only be able to see the custom field (or even any other field) in the JSON response as long as that field has a value stored to it on that work item.

Comment: 's suggestion worked for me.

Comment: That's silly that blank custom fields don't show up as an empty string

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get a filed value of specific work item, simply use WIQL and client library.

For example , if your work item have some custom fields and you could try to get these fields by querying with WorkItemCollection, like this:

```
  WorkItemCollection queryResults = workItemStore.Query("Select [State], [Work Item Type], [Title], [Resource Development], [Customize.Complexity.Development] FROM WorkItems " +

                                                "WHERE [Work Item Type] = '" + tipoWorkItem + "' AND [State] <> 'Closed' AND [Team Project] = '" + teamProjectName + "'");
```

Finally get the custom fields by looping the result, like this:

```
        foreach (WorkItem workItem in queryResults)

        {

             variable = workItem.Fields["Customize.Resource.Development"].Value;

        }
```

For more details you could also take a look at this similar question: [How to get Whats New field value from TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930704/how-to-get-whats-new-field-value-from-tfs)